# How can I convert two strings to a hash in perl?

Tags: string, perl, hash, dictionary, split

i have two strings:

```
my $wTime = "00:00-06:00 / 06:00-09:00 / 09:00-17:00 / 17:00-23:00 / 23:00-00:00";
my $wTemp = "17.0 °C / 21.0 °C / 17.0 °C / 21.0 °C / 17.0 °C";
```

I would like to join these strings to a hash, where the first part of each timescale is a key, e.g.:

```
$hash = (
  "00:00" => "17.0 °C",
  "06:00" => "21.0 °C",
  "09:00" => "17.0 °C",
  "17:00" => "21.0 °C",
  "23:00" => "17.0 °C"
);
```

I have tried some variants of map and split but i've got some mysterious results ;-)

```
%hash = map {split /\s*\/\s*/, $_ } split /-/, $wTime;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a good first question. It would be better if you would show some of these `map` and `split` things you've tried. You can only learn from your mistakes if people can point them out. ;-)

Comment: as i told before: i've tried to split $wTime with e.g. `%hash = map {split /\s*\/\s*/, $_ } split /-/, $wTime;` but this split every timestring into a key. there are some other variants i've tried also.

Comment: I took the liberty to add this to your question. You can also [edit] your question yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`List::MoreUtils` `zip` / `mesh` function](https://metacpan.org/module/List%253A%253AMoreUtils):

```
my @time_ranges = split ' / ', $wTime;
my @times = map { (split '-', $_)[0] } @time_ranges;
my @temps = split ' / ', $wTemp;

use List::MoreUtils qw(zip);
my %hash = zip @times, @temps;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I've forgotten: without any other module.

Answer (score 2):

One more way:

```
my $wTime = "00:00-06:00 / 06:00-09:00 / 09:00-17:00 / 17:00-23:00 / 23:00-00:00";
my $wTemp = "17.0 °C / 21.0 °C / 17.0 °C / 21.0 °C / 17.0 °C";

my %h1;
@h1{$wTime=~/([\d:]+)-/g}=split(m! / !,$wTemp);
```

Comment: What a pity you can't make it in one line (i.e. statement) ;)

Comment: @Xaerxess, Sure you can. `my %h1 = do { my %h; @h{...}=...; %h };`. There are ways without using `do` or `;`.

Comment: Yeah, I use `do` sometimes ;) Never underestimate Perl's powers of putting everything in one line...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a verbose solution without List::MoreUtils.

```
my $wTime = "00:00-06:00 / 06:00-09:00 / 09:00-17:00 / 17:00-23:00 / 23:00-00:00";
my $wTemp = "17.0 °C / 21.0 °C / 17.0 °C / 21.0 °C / 17.0 °C";

my @time = map { (split /-/, $_)[0] } split m! / !, $wTime;
my @temp = split m! / !, $wTemp;

my %hash;
for (my $i=0; $i <= $#time; $i++) { # Iterate the times via their index...
  # This only works if we have an equal number of temps and times of course.
  $hash{$time[$i]} = $temp[$i];
}
```

Comment: this works, but not completely! :-) the last timescale `23:00-00:00` is ignored.

Comment: `<$#time` in the for loop should be either `<=$#time` or `<@time`

Comment: You might also consider `@hash{@time} = @temp`, using a hash slice assignment.

Comment: @TLP that would be a lot more perlish, but I'll stick with this solution for demonstration's sake. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Create both lists.

```
my @wTimes = map /([^-]+)/, split qr{ / }, $wTime;
my @wTemps = split qr{ / }, $wTemp;
```

Then use a hash slice.

```
my %hash;
@hash{@wTimes} = @wTemps;
```